# Why does heroku say there is a dyno running after "ps:scale" but then "ps" says no dynos running?

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-cli

I built a Django app and I'm trying to use heroku to publish it online. I've tried running the app locally and it works fine, but when I try `heroku ps:scale web=1` as soon as i try `heroku ps` it says that there are no dynos running. Why is this?

Thank you for your help and understanding!

In the image below my CLI was glitching out so it had text where it didn't belong. I did enter `heroku ps` not `herokeroku ps eroku ps`.

[image: CLI now running dyno. No dynos running.]

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by an error in deployment "Deployment Failed". Read the corresponding release log to find out why.